# Angular JS - ng-repeat first element from an array of arrays

Tags: arrays, angularjs

I have a set of data like this

```
$scope.data = [
["Orange", 3],
["Blue", 2],
["Pink", 1],
["Red", 1],
["Black", 2],
];
```

I would like to do an ng-repeat that outupts just the first element of each array inside the main array (in other words, just the colors, but not the numbers). So far I made this code

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="color in data">
         <div ng-repeat="n in color">
          {{n}}
         </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

You can find a jsFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/k1na4t5z/)

I tried to use `ng-repeat"n[0] in color"`, but the output is not the desired. Any idea would be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div ng-repeat="item in data">
    {{item[0]}}
</div>
```

Comment: I marked the other one as correct as it was the first to come, but this one is also correct (basically is the same). Thanks anyway!

Comment: @Joe82, well, technically my answer was the first ;) Check the answer time, but it's no problem. I'm glad to help.

Answer (score 1):

Change your template to this:

```
<div ng-controller="myCtrl">
   <div ng-repeat="color in data">
      <div>
         {{color[0]}}
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

You only need the first item, so there's no need to use `ng-repeat`. Just access it directly!

Comment: True that. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: Absolutely no problem!